# Rails 5 - How to search a string as per the order which we enter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, search

In rails 5, I am using `searchkick` gem for the first time, I want a search result for auto-complete list as per the letter which I enter.

"Cleanliness", "Taste", "Service" these are data which I want to show as a suggestions(list)

Now the current search is working like,

When `misspellings: false`, if I type "c" then only "Cleanliness" will show.

When `misspellings: 2`, if I type "c" then all 3 "Cleanliness", "Taste", "Service" will show.

I want to show first "Cleanliness" and then "Service"

In model,

```
searchkick word_start: [:name], index_name: -> { "#{name.tableize}-#{Rails.application.secrets.elasticsearch_index}-#{I18n.locale}" }
include ReIndex
```

In controller,

```
Model.search(params[:attribute], fields: [:name], match: :word_start, misspellings: 2).results
```

In Gemfile.lock,

```
searchkick (2.3.0)
elasticsearch (5.0.4)
```

Working scenario should be like,

- If I type "c" then 'Cleanliness' should come first then 'Service' should display. Two values should display in auto-completion list,
  right now it is fetching only 'Cleanliness' because of first letter "c".
- In 'Service', "c" is not taking for search, it should fetch the same.
- If I type "a" then no results, actually it should show "Taste" because "a" is present over here.

Please help me to solve this issue. Also let me know how this `misspellings` works in detail.